# How to add disabled to html helper based on condition?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-helper

I'm trying to prevent user from using input in some condition but for disabling it if I add `disabled` to it, it will disable no matter that its value is `true` or `false`.

This is my code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.inputName, new { @disabled = (condition ? "true" : "false") })
```

In any condition it will be disabled.

Comment: By adding `@disabled` to attributes you make your control disabled. It value doesn't matter

Comment: Yes but how can I add disabled as attribute to html helpers?

Comment: You can create object variable with custom set of attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because whether to disabled depend on your `disabled` attribute instead of the `disabled` attribute value

Here is an example

```html
<p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled="" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled="true" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled="false" /></p>
```

if you don't want to use Js to control your attribute we can judge that by `if` condition true to create the element with `disabled` otherwise not.

```
@if(condition) 
{
    Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.inputName, new { @disabled = "true" })
}
else
{
    Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.inputName)
}
```

otherwise we can create an extension method for that.

```
public static class TextBoxForExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        object htmlAttributes, 
        bool disabled
    )
    {
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        if (disabled)
        {
            attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
        }
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);
    }
}
```

Then we can use like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.inputName, new{},condition)
```

Comment: As I checked `html helper` wont work inside @{ } but making new html helper will work so as I understand there is no way to add attribute like a string right?

Comment: I don't know why when i used @{ } it didn't work but with @if{ } it worked thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in comment to this question you can add variable:

```
var myAttributes = condition ? new {@disabled = true, /* add some more here*/} : new {/*add more here*/}
```

Then you can add it in your helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.inputName, myAttributes)
```